# If two nxn matrices have the same (non-zero) determinant, they can be transformed into the same form by gaussian elimination - true or false?

Tags: linear-algebra, gaussian-elimination

If the determinants are 0, the theorem is obviously false, but what happens otherwise? And if it does not hold, could we add some other conditions to make it true?

My motivation for this came to me while trying to prove the elementary fact that if $ \lambda_1, ..., \lambda_n$ are eigenvalues of a matrix A, then $ detA = \lambda_1...\lambda_n$. Now I'm aware of the quick proof for this using the characteristic polynomial evaluated at 0, but I found my attempt more interesting.

First, I used the fact that A can be transformed into a reduced form $ \pmatrix{c_1 & . & . \\
. & .... & . \\
0 & ... & 0 & c_n }$ with $ \det{A} = c_1...c_n$. To prove the theorem, we'd obviously want to show that $ c_1, ..., c_n$ are precisely the roots of the characteristic polynomial for A, that is $ \det{(A - \lambda I)}$. But they are precisely the roots of the polynomial $ (c_1-\lambda)...(c_n-\lambda) = \det{\pmatrix{c_1 - \lambda & . & . \\
. & .... & . \\
0 & ... & 0 & c_n - \lambda}}$. So, we should also get that the last equation equals $ \det{(A-\lambda I)}$. So if I could somehow show that $ A-\lambda I $ can be transformed by gaussian elimination into  $ \pmatrix{c_1 - \lambda & . & . \\
. & .... & . \\
0 & ... & 0 & c_n - \lambda} $, my proof would work. And that's what motivated the question.

Comment: The Jordan form might be an easier way of proving this...

Comment: Gaussian elimination (at least when it's normally done), is changing coordinates in the domain and target independently, but the determinant is something for an operator on a single space, so you have to change coordinates in the same way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any invertible matrix can be row-reduced to the identity matrix and back, which means that you can row-reduce any invertible matrix into any invertible matrix (of the same size, obviously).

Now, that said, row-reduction does not preserve determinants, so I fail to see how your argument goes.

Comment: Unless I got something terribly wrong, taking a row and adding to it some scalar multiple of another row shouldn't change the determinant, as it is an alternating tensor as a function of the rows(or columns).
But it's true that multiplying a row by a scalar will change the determinant, so we can't reduce a matrix to the identity. I'd need to find a way to reduce the matrix to the form I've descrived without using scalar multiplication. I guess I'll have to work on this proof some more.

Comment: You are right. But you wouldn't be able to pivot, so I'm not sure how far you can get without multiplying by scalars.